# How to add a new field in yii 1.1.5? I tried to added a new field into my DB and changed my model and view. But I got an undifined error

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I am new to yii1.1.5. I added a new filed into my tbl_project table and changed my model and view. But when I wanted to save the data that I inputted to mysql, I got a error, it said "Property "Project.balance" is not defined."

I tried to clear up the cashe but I could not solve this problem.

My model.php

```
    <?php

    /**
     * This is the model class for table "tbl_project".
     *
     * The followings are the available columns in table 'tbl_project':
     * @property integer $id
     * @property string $name
     * @property string $description
     * @property string balance
     * @property string $create_time
     * @property integer $create_user_id
     * @property string $update_time
     * @property integer $update_user_id
     */
    class Project extends TrackStarActiveRecord
    {
        /**
         * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
         * @return Project the static model class
         */
        public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
        {
            return parent::model($className);
        }

        /**
         * @return string the associated database table name
         */
        public function tableName()
        {
            return 'tbl_project';
        }

        /**
         * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
            // will receive user inputs.
            return array(
                array('balance,create_user_id, update_user_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
                array('name', 'length', 'max'=>128),
                array('description,balance,create_time, update_time', 'safe'),

                // The following rule is used by search().
                // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                array('id, name, description,balance,create_time, create_user_id, update_time, update_user_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
                array('name', 'required'),
                array('description', 'required'),
            );
        }

        /**
         * @return array relational rules.
         */
        public function relations()
        {
            // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
            // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
            return array(
                'issues'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Issue', 'project_id'),
                'users'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User', 'tbl_project_user_assignment(project_id,user_id)'),
            );
        }

        /**
         * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
         */
        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return array(
                'id' => 'ID',
                'name' => '姓名',
                'description' => '描述',
                'balance'=>'余额',
                'create_time' => '创建时间',
                'create_user_id' => '创建用户ID',
                'update_time' => '更新时间',
                'update_user_id' => '更新用户ID',
            );
        }

        /**
         * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
         * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
         */
        public function search()
        {
            // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
            // should not be searched.

            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

            $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
            $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
            $criteria->compare('description',$this->description,true);
            $criteria->compare('balance',$this->balance,true);
            $criteria->compare('create_time',$this->create_time,true);
            $criteria->compare('create_user_id',$this->create_user_id);
            $criteria->compare('update_time',$this->update_time,true);
            $criteria->compare('update_user_id',$this->update_user_id);

            return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
            ));
        }
        public function getUserOptions()
        {
             $usersArray=CHtml::listData($this->users,'id','username');


            return $usersArray;
        }
        public function associateUserToRole($role, $user_id)
        {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_project_user_role (project_id, user_id,role) VALUES (:project_id, :user_id, :role)";
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
        $command->bindValue(":project_id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $command->bindValue(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $command->bindValue(":role", $role, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        return $command->execute();
        }
        public function removeUserFromRole($role, $user_id)
        {
            $sql="DELETE FROM tbl_project_user_role WHERE project_id=:project_id AND user_id=:user_id AND role=:role";
            $command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
            $command->blindValue(":project_id",$this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $command->blindValue(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::RARAM_INT);
            $command->blindValue(":role", $role, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            return $command->execute();
        }
    /*  public function isUserInRole($role)
        {
            $sql="SELECT role FROM tbl_project_user_role WHERE project_id=:project_id AND user_id=:user_id AND role=:role";
            $command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);

            $command->bindValue(":project_id",$this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $command->bindValue(":user_id", Yii::app()->user->getId(),PDO::PARAM_INT );
            $command->bindValue(":role",$role, PDO::PAPAM_STR);
            return $command->execute()==1?true:false;

        } */
            public function isUserInRole($role)
            {
                $sql = "SELECT role FROM tbl_project_user_role WHERE project_id=:projectId AND user_id=:userId AND role=:role";
                $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
                $command->bindValue(":projectId", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $command->bindValue(":userId", Yii::app()->user->getId(),PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $command->bindValue(":role", $role, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                return $command->execute()==1 ? true : false;
            }

        public static function getUserRoleOptions()
        {
            return CHtml::listData(Yii::app()->authManager->getRoles(),'name','name');
        }
        public function associateUserToProject($user)
        {
            $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_project_user_assignment(project_id,user_id) VALUES (:project_id,:user_id)";
            $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
            $command->bindValue(":project_id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $command->bindValue(":user_id", $user->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            return $command->execute();
        }
        /* public function isUserInProject($user)
        {
            $sql="SELECT user_id FROM tbl_project_user_assignment WHERE project_id=:project_id AND user_id=:user_id";
            $command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
            var_dump($command);exit;
            $command->blindValue(":project_id",$this->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $command->blindValue(":user_id",$user->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            return $command->execute()==1 ? true:false;
        } */
        public function isUserInProject($user)
        {
            $sql ="SELECT user_id FROM tbl_project_user_assignment WHERE project_id=:projectId AND user_id=:userId";
            $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
            $command->bindValue(":projectId", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $command->bindValue(":userId", $user->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            return $command->execute()==1;
        }
    }

    My view.php

    <div class="form">

    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'project-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    )); ?>

        <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

        <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'姓名'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'余额'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'balance'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'描述'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'description',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'description'); ?>
        </div>




        <div class="row buttons">
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
        </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

    </div><!-- form -->

    My Mysql:

    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
    -- version 4.6.4
    -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
    --
    -- Host: 127.0.0.1
    -- Generation Time: Jun 27, 2019 at 10:15 AM
    -- Server version: 5.7.14
    -- PHP Version: 5.6.25

    SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
    SET time_zone = "+00:00";


    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

    --
    -- Database: `yxbeauty`
    --

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `tbl_project`
    --

    CREATE TABLE `tbl_project` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
      `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
      `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `create_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `update_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `tbl_project`
    --

    INSERT INTO `tbl_project` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `create_time`, `create_user_id`, `update_time`, `update_user_id`) VALUES
    (1, '饼子脸', '测试', NULL, NULL, '2019-06-27 15:07:23', 12),
    (2, 'Test Project15', '测试', '2018-12-16 13:56:34', 5, '2018-12-16 14:38:28', 12),
    (3, '天天华盛顿', '天天华盛顿', '2019-06-27 15:42:56', 12, '2019-06-27 15:42:56', 12);

    --
    -- Indexes for dumped tables
    --

    --
    -- Indexes for table `tbl_project`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_project`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
    --

    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tbl_project`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_project`
      MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;


    CException
    Description
    Property "Project.balance" is not defined.

    Source File
    E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(113)

    00101:      */
    00102:     public function __get($name)
    00103:     {
    00104:         if(isset($this->_attributes[$name]))
    00105:             return $this->_attributes[$name];
    00106:         else if(isset($this->getMetaData()->columns[$name]))
    00107:             return null;
    00108:         else if(isset($this->_related[$name]))
    00109:             return $this->_related[$name];
    00110:         else if(isset($this->getMetaData()->relations[$name]))
    00111:             return $this->getRelated($name);
    00112:         else
    00113:             return parent::__get($name);
    00114:     }
    00115:
    00116:     /**
    00117:      * PHP setter magic method.
    00118:      * This method is overridden so that AR attributes can be accessed like properties.
    00119:      * @param string $name property name
    00120:      * @param mixed $value property value
    00121:      */
    00122:     public function __set($name,$value)
    00123:     {
    00124:         if($this->setAttribute($name,$value)===false)
    00125:         {
    Stack Trace
    #0 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(113): CComponent->__get('balance')
    #1 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\validators\CNumberValidator.php(56): CActiveRecord->__get('balance')
    #2 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\validators\CValidator.php(184): CNumberValidator->validateAttribute(Object(Project), 'balance')
    #3 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\base\CModel.php(150): CValidator->validate(Object(Project), NULL)
    #4 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(766): CModel->validate(NULL)
    #5 E:\projects\yxbeauty\yxbeauty\protected\controllers\ProjectController.php(100): CActiveRecord->save()
    #6 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(57): ProjectController->actionCreate()
    #7 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\web\CController.php(300): CInlineAction->run()
    #8 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(133): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
    #9 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\web\filters\CFilter.php(41): CFilterChain->run()
    #10 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\web\CController.php(1084): CFilter->filter(Object(CFilterChain))
    #11 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\web\filters\CInlineFilter.php(59): CController->filterAccessControl(Object(CFilterChain))
    #12 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(130): CInlineFilter->filter(Object(CFilterChain))
    #13 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\web\CController.php(283): CFilterChain->run()
    #14 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\web\CController.php(257): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
    #15 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(324): CController->run('create')
    #16 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(121): CWebApplication->runController('project/create')
    #17 E:\projects\yxbeauty\framework\base\CApplication.php(135): CWebApplication->processRequest()
    #18 E:\projects\yxbeauty\yxbeauty\index.php(13): CApplication->run()
    #19 {main}
    2019-06-27 10:02:05 Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) PHP/5.6.25 Yii Framework/1.1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by

1.add the field to the physical table(difine the data type, utf8 and so on).
2.change the model file.
3.change the view file.

I have two mistakes,

1.I had to add a public property as in my model file as below.

```
class Project extends TrackStarActiveRecord
 {
   public $balance;
   ...
```

2.I had a mistype in my view file.

```
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'余额'); ?>
    <?php echo $form>textField($model,'balance', // here must be 'balance'
    array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128));?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'balance'); ?>
    </div>
```

refer:
https://stackoverrun.com/ja/q/2463502